Is it possible to apply a 'holdout' to a transparent 'image as plane'?
Does anyone know how to apply a 'Holdout' texture to just the solid image in a transparent image PNG and not the blank area around it?
Thanks in advance


You could use the image as a factor between the Holdout node and the image itself (instead of the image you could use an image with the same background color, or a pure color), use a ColorRamp if you want to make sure that you don't see any black contour:


Perfect! Many thanks!
